# How to convert Google Spreadsheets pivot table to Excel?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, pivot-table, excel-pivot

I have a Google Spreadsheet with the following data:

[image: Data in GS]

I have copied the data to Excel (office 365):

[image: Data in Excel]

You can access the data here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Hn8wdcfNlMLNZNgDnFAJfYJ2g1OIW3rKGvoacHU5xrQ/edit?usp=sharing
Or:

| **Company** | Field ID | Field area (ha) | Crop in 2024 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **A** | 1 | 62 | B |
| **B** | 2 | 13 | Alfalfa |
| **C** | 3 | 19 | N |
| **B** | 4 | 72 | Sz |
| **B** | 5 | 48 | Sz |
| **C** | 6 | 69 | Alfalfa |
| **A** | 7 | 74 | K |
| **B** | 8 | 4 | Á |
| **A** | 9 | 25 | Alfalfa |
| **A** | 10 | 80 | B |
| **C** | 11 | 4 | N |
| **C** | 12 | 21 | K |
| **A** | 13 | 63 | K |
| **A** | 12 | 18 | Alfalfa |
| **B** | 15 | 76 | B |

I would like to calculate the sum of the areas where the "`Crop in 2024`" is not alfalfa. For this purpose, I use the formula: `=SUM(FILTER('Field area (ha)'; 'Crop in 2024' <> "Alfalfa"))`. The name of the column where the calculation takes place is "`Szántó`".

I have a working solution in Google Spreadsheets:

[image: Working solution in GS]

However, when I try to copy my solution to Excel (office 365) it does not work:

[image: Not working in Excel]

**Note:**
If I change the "Summarize by" value in Google Spreadsheets from Custom (Egyéni) to SUM, it does not work in Google Spreadsheets. It produces the same output as Excel does.
[image]

How could I convert my pivot table to Excel? If possible, I would like to use this formula.

Comment: For some reason the markdown table appears as simple text (for me), however, in the preview, it shows a real table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select all of the data and, on the *Insert* tab of the ribbon, click on *Pivot Table* -> *From Table/Range*
[image: Screenshot illustrating pivot table insertion]

On the window that pops up next, ensure that the highlighted box is checked
[image: Screenshot illustrating addition to Data Model]

Having clicked OK on the previous pop up, the *Power Pivot* tab of the ribbon should be selected, and then *Measures* -> *New Measure*
[image: Screenshot illustrating selection of measure]

On the window that pops up, a value should be entered in the *Measure name* field
[image: Screenshot illustrating measure definition]

(the *Table Name* field above is populated with *Range* because the selected data were a regular (un-named) Range/Table)

and this

```
=SUMX(FILTER(Range,Range[Crop in 2024]<>"Alfalfa"),Range[Field area (ha)])
```

should be entered in the *Formula* box.

Having clicked OK on the previous window, the new measure should automatically be added to the *Values* panel
[image: Screenshot illustrating 'formula-driven' result]

Comment: I knew about this solution, however, in reality, it does not meet my demands. I would like to make it work with a formula. Is that possible?

Comment: @Marci, answer updated to reflect use of PP measure

Comment: Thank you very much! It works. I have never used Power Pivot in Excel before, as I do not regularly use Excel. Now it's time for me to look into it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't necessarily need a pivot, this would work:

```
=LET(u,UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A16,D2:D16<>"Alfalfa")),
     s,SUMIFS(C2:C16,A2:A16,u,D2:D16,"<>"&"Alfalfa"),
HSTACK(u,s))
```

or

```
=LET(range,   A2:D16,
     exclude, {"Alfalfa","B"},
     company, INDEX(range,,1),
     area,    INDEX(range,,3),
     crop,    INDEX(range,,4),
unique_comp,  UNIQUE(FILTER(company,ISNA(XMATCH(crop,exclude)))),
sum_area,     MMULT(N(TOROW(company)=unique_comp),area*ISNA(XMATCH(crop,exclude))),
HSTACK(unique_comp,sum_area))
```

Where you can change the `exclude` and `range` parameter to your needs.

[image]

Comment: I need a pivot. I MUST use a pivot table. I knew the formula way to solve it already. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Can I ask why, if you knew the formula way already, then this would update live, while pivot needs manual interference. Why not use the pivot table and filter out the name, as previously suggested by Spectral Instance, or convert your data to table and use slicer.

Comment: It is because my colleague is going to use the solution. There is no way that he will be able to understand the way you (and I) would solve the problem. I need a way, which I can easily explain to him, and as he is 100x more familiar with pivot tables than with formulas, using pivots is the best way. I use Python (and SPSS) instead of Excel, therefore I am not so familiar with Excel solutions.